# How to get the Serial Number of a disk by corresponding file in linux?

Tags: linux, command, io, disk

I know that for a disk in linux, we can use commands such as `hdparm` or `smartctl` to get its basic information. 
But for the implementation of these commands, I think all of them are implemented by reading the corresponding file of a disk in linux. For example, to get the size of a device */dev/sda*, we can use `cat /sys/block/sda/size` instead of using command such `hdparm` or `smartctl`. So the question is how to get the serial number of a disk by reading its corresponding file directly.

Comment: `grep SERIAL_SHORT /run/udev/data/b8*` (your first drive would be `b8:0`, the second `b8:16`, the third `b8:32` etc)

Comment: i don't think disk serial # resides in an existing file somewhere (such as under /proc).  When using `smartcl -all /dev/sda` or `hdparm -I` those get the information directly from the drive (from the sata/sas controller).

Comment: similiarly if you have *N* disks as a raid 5/6 behind a controller, the serial numbers of each disk is not in some file but rather can be obtained with `smartctl` or `hdparm`.  linux has no reason to go fetch disk serial number and save it in some file.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replicate how these tools work? Or you want to know what file contains the data? Why don't you just lookup how these implement retrieving the data? The code is freely published.

Answer (score 1):

I just have a try. It do get the serial by ioctl. This is some output of strace:

```
open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)   = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
ioctl(3, SG_IO, {'S', SG_DXFER_FROM_DEV, cmd[6]=[12, 00, 00, 00, 24, 00], mx_sb_len=32, iovec_count=0, dxfer_len=36, timeout=20000, flags=0, data[36]=["\0\0\5\2[\0\0\0ATA     WDC WD5000LPVX-0"...], status=00, masked_status=00, sb[0]=[], host_status=0, driver_status=0, resid=0, duration=0, info=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SG_IO, {'S', SG_DXFER_FROM_DEV, cmd[16]=[85, 08, 0e, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, ec, 00], mx_sb_len=32, iovec_count=0, dxfer_len=512, timeout=20000, flags=0, data[512]=["zB\377?7\310\20\0\0\0\0\0?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0    W -DXW11"...], status=00, masked_status=00, sb[0]=[], host_status=0, driver_status=0, resid=0, duration=0, info=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SG_IO, {'S', SG_DXFER_FROM_DEV, cmd[16]=[85, 08, 0e, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, ec, 00], mx_sb_len=32, iovec_count=0, dxfer_len=512, timeout=20000, flags=0, data[512]=["zB\377?7\310\20\0\0\0\0\0?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0    W -DXW11"...], status=00, masked_status=00, sb[0]=[], host_status=0, driver_status=0, resid=0, duration=0, info=0}) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, at least on my system. The solution rely on `/run/udev/data` dump data.

Below is an bash script sample:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a DRIVES <<< "$(ls /dev/sd*[0-9] 2>/dev/null)"
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a NVME_DRIVES <<< "$(ls /dev/nvme*[0-9]n[0-9] 2>/dev/null)"

DRIVES+=("${NVME_DRIVES[@]}")

for drive in "${DRIVES[@]}"; do
  drive=${drive##*/}
  IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a _uevent <<< "$(grep -e "MAJOR" -e "MINOR" "/sys/class/block/${drive}/uevent"| sort | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')"
  _serial=$(grep "ID_SERIAL=" "/run/udev/data/b${_uevent[0]}:${_uevent[1]}" | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')

  echo "[${drive}] serial: ${_serial}  short: ${_serial##*_}"
done
```

The logic of the script is as following:

- getting list of drives in the system
- read for each drive device block address
- fetch the data from udev meta

The steps were deducted from strace of  `lsblk --nodeps -no serial /dev/sda`

Answer (score 0):

You could use strace to find how smartctl get the serial number of a disk. CMD line likes this: strace smartctl -a /dev/sda. Maybe it just get the serial by ioctl.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use lsblk command to do that. Step one is get all of SCSI devices only. Also all partitions, slaves and holder devices are ignored.

```
~$ lsblk -S  
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL             REV TRAN  
sdb  1:0:1:0    disk Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0  
sr0  5:0:0:0    rom  Msft     Virtual CD/ROM   1.0  ata  
sdc  3:0:0:10   disk Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0  
sda  0:0:0:0    disk Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0
```

Then you get the serial number for each disk

```
~$ lsblk --nodeps -no serial /dev/sda  
600224807cc344ea899e344614ead465
```

And use **strace** command to see deeply how does lsblk get the serial number? I did do this, but no sure what I see was right. You can try it for you.

**lsblk** needs to be able to lookup sysfs *- a filesystem for exporting kernel objects -* path by major:minor, which is done done by using /sys/dev/block.

Also you can refer man page of sysfs at [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html).

Answer (score 0):

on Linux for disk sda:

```
egrep '^E:ID_SERIAL' /run/udev/data/b$(basename $(readlink --canonicalize /sys/block/sda/bdi))
E:ID_SERIAL=Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_500GB_S3R3NF0JA99600T
E:ID_SERIAL_SHORT=S3R3NF0JA99600T
```

```
date && uname --kernel-release
Tue Nov  2 11:50:37 AM PDT 2021
5.13.0-20-generic
```

Answer (score -2):

You could also use `/proc/partitions` to find that info.

That file gives you the size in number of *blocks* that all your partitions have, But also gives you the same information for your entire disks.

Comment: I don't need information of number of blocks but the serial number.